# SpringData JPA native query gives java.sql Data instead of LocalDate

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, localdate

I'm having JPA repository with a native query like below(actual query is complex):

```
@Query(value="select registration_num, registration_date from registration_details", nativeQuery="true")
List<Object[]> getDateDetails();
```

I'm putting this list value into a map with registration_num as key and registration_date as key.

The problem is that query is return date of `java.sql` type but I need it in LocalDate type.
For every value to put in map, I have to do casting like `(Date)obj[1]` and then `sqlDate.toLocalDate()` to use further. This is very inefficient. Is there any way to return LocalDate from query or return list of a class with two properties registrationNum and registrationDate.

for example:

```
@Query(value="select registration_num, registration_date from registration_details", nativeQuery="true")
List<MyDTO> getDetails(); 

class MyDTO {
  private String registrationNum;
  private LocalDate registrationDate;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Answer (score 0):

In the recent spring version it automatically converted. For older version, you can use `AttributeConverter`, it auto-applied for every LocalDate type in entity class.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate localDate) {
        return (localDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(localDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }

}
```